# Graphin sin (e^x)

Tags: graphing-functions

Hi I was wondering if the limits of x were [0 < x < 360] how would you be able to graph f(x) = sin (e^x). I only was able to workout the range of the graph which will be -1 < f(x) < 1 but not sure how to draw the graph.
Is it possible to obtain a more "friendlier" version so we can apply transformation rule to the function?

Comment: What do you mean by a friendlier version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $e^{360}\approx 2.2\cdot 10^{156}$ is so huge, $\sin(e^x)$ will go over an enormous number of cycles.  The graph will just look like a solid band once $x$ gets larger than a few.  You won't be able to see the details of the graph at all.